# Why can my NLA strip only be 10 000 frames long?

Tags: animation, keyframes, path, nla-editor

I have NLA strip with path animation, But it seems like I can only do animation for about 10 000 frames if I'm using NLA strips?

Really?

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I clicked the button called "NOW" right beyond the red rectangle on the screen, and it helped so great. ;D

Working with Blender is so emotional <3